# Load Midi from local path?

Tags: java

Where filename is the midi file. I want to load a full path (from local harddisk) into the getSequence but it doesn't accept except the filename itself. Sorry that I not good in Java and wish there is a solution for my need.

song = MidiSystem.getSequence(getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename));

and the Stackoverflow's richtext toolbar is missing in my Firefox browse?

[Update]

try {
        song = MidiSystem.getSequence(new FileInputStream(filename));
            sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
            sequencer.setSequence(song);
            sequencer.open();
            sequencer.addMetaEventListener(this);
            sequencer.start();
        } catch (InvalidMidiDataException e) {
            System.out.println("Bad midi file: "
                + filename);
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {
            System.out.println("No sequencer available");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not read: "
                + filename);
            System.exit(1);
        }

Answer (score 1):

`getRecourceAsStream()` is helpful only if the file is withing the classpath. If you have the file on the file system you should call:

```
song = MidiSystem.getSequence(new FileInputStream("/path/to/midi/file"));
```

Comment: Your code work the same way but I got a message that throw an exception "Could not read".

Comment: Would you please refer to my update post with new portion of code.

Comment: My file name is just an example - you need to refer to an actual file in your file system, of which you have read access.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

song = MidiSystem.getSequence(getClass().getResourceAsStream("@filextension"));

or you could use filereader.

Comment: am I to type in exactly as @filextension?